# 'watch'-ing curl yields unexpected output

Tags: io-redirection, curl, watch

I'm trying to `watch curl` for live feedback on HTTP tweaks. However, when I execute the command, the output is garbled with some download stats. I've tried sending `curl`'s `stderr` to `/dev/null`, to no avail.

When playing with `curl` on it's own, this output seems nowhere to be found.

What am I missing?

[edit]

the full command line I'm running is actually

`watch --color -d "curl -I sandbox.dev | ccze"`, because I want colorized output. It seems that if I remove the `ccze` pipe things are a little better, altough the download stats are still there.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It seems curl does print the progress stats only when stdout is not a terminal. (e.g. `curl -I sandbox.dev|cat` would give you these results, too)  You can disable these, however.

From the manpage

```
   -s/--silent
          Silent or quiet mode. Don't show progress meter or
          error messages. Makes Curl mute.
```

Comment: guess I should of RTFM :) anyway, thank you!